# Using Temporary External Table in Big Query as a Source to append data to another table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Command 1 is working fine. But Command 2 is not working. My intention is to load data into a permanent table by querying temporary external table ( may be i will perform some data cleansing on the data of external table and load it).

Is this possible?

Regards,
Sreekanth

Command 1:

```
bq --location=US query --external_table_definition=ORDER_DEL::INTEGRATION_ID:STRING@CSV=gs://cloud-dw-poc.appspot.com/PREPARED_LAYER/results-20180801-181812.csv 'SELECT INTEGRATION_ID FROM ORDER_DEL;'
```

Command 2:

```
bq query --append_table=true --batch=false --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=cloud-dw-poc:Z_NOT_USED.ORDER_DEL --external_table_definition=ORDER_DEL::INTEGRATION_ID:STRING@CSV=gs://cloud-dw-poc.appspot.com/PREPARED_LAYER/results-20180801-181812.csv 'SELECT INTEGRATION_ID FROM ORDER_DEL;'
```

Comment: Which is the error when run the second query?

Comment: It does not proceed, looks like waiting for some more input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with the commands, it worked on my end. You may consider to do the same test in order to find what is going on here. My test has done with a public dataset `bikeshare_stations`. First of all, I run the following query and save it into a new table:

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_stations`
```

Then, I downloaded the result as `CSV` and uploaded into the `GCS`. After that, I run the following command:

```
bq query --append_table=true --batch=false --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLE --external_table_definition=TABLE::station_id:INTEGER@CSV=CSV_GCS_PATH 'SELECT * FROM TABLE;'
```

This may help you to compare the scenario and find the cause.

Comment: Thank you. Its working.  I gave BQ Admin and Storage Admin privilege. Not sure if that helped.

Comment: Could you solve your problem? What I did is pretty similar than you and the command is working fine. If you still experiencing the issue, you may consider to use this test to compare with your use case and find insights about the issue.